# 'InfoKey' is not a member type of 'UIImagePickerController'

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uikit

I am getting this error:

> 'InfoKey' is not a member type of 'UIImagePickerController'

I had wasted time searching on the issue but failed.

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        return
    }
}
```

Xcode 9.4, Swift 4.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are attempting to use the newer iOS 12 API which requires Xcode 10. If you are using Xcode 9.4 then you are using iOS 11 and you need to use the soon to be older API.

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Works now. Thank you!

Comment: I use Xcode 10.1 beta 3, but if I don't use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` I see the same error as in the original question. What's strange is that a command-click opens the definition of the supposedly undefined `InfoKey` struct. Huh?

Comment: @Theo you may also need to make sure you are using Swift 4.2 (in build settings / swift language version)

Comment: Swift 5 iOS 12 use `guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]`

Comment: @andrewbuilder Your comment would be for Swift 4.2 and later. But the question was about a user trying to use the newer API in an older version of Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to remove the `private` key word. it might be added to silence a warning.

The syntax that you gave is from an different version of swift than 4

here is the new one

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

Comment: The syntax in the question is actually correct for Xcode 10 / Swift 4.2+, minus the private keyword issue of course.

Answer (score -2):

For me: I had to change swift version in xCode to Swift 5